# SSH connection via PHP - Laravel

Tags: php, bash, laravel, laravel-5, ssh

## Hello everyone

I'm going to try to explain my problem as clear as possible, feel free to ask me more precision if you didn't understand what I meant and forgive my English this is not my mother tongue.

---

## My goal

What I want to do looks simple. Let's say I have 2 servers: S1 and S2.
**S1** is the server on which one I have my Laravel 5.5 installed and running.
**S2** is a server where I have multiples PHP scripts.
I want to run a PHP script (which is on S2) from a simple click on a button in my Laravel App.
The command I want to run is `php theNameOfMyFiles`

---

## The things you have to know

1. In command line, I can connect in SSH to S2 via S1: `ssh -tt -p 2222 myRemoteUser@myRemoteIp`. This is working properly.
2. Most of my test will show some tries of folder creation because it is easier to see if a folder has been created instead of checking if a script is running.

---

## My different tries

To reach that goal, I tried a bunch of things. First of all, I am using [Laravelcollective SSH 5.2](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/ssh) to be able to use SSH from my Laravel app.
My configuration file `config/remote.php`, this is where I specify my remote server connections :

```
return [
    default' => 'S1',
   'connections' => [
    'S1' => [
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'username'  => 'myUsername',
        'password'  => 'myPassword',
        'key'       => '',
        'keytext'   => '',
        'keyphrase' => '',
        'agent'     => '',
        'timeout'   => 10,
    ],
    'S2' => [
        'host'      => 'myRemoteIP',
        'username'  => 'myRemoteUser',
        'port'      => '2222',
        'password'  => '',
        'key'       => '',
        'keytext'   => '',
        'keyphrase' => '',
        'agent'     => '',
        'timeout'   => 30,
        'directory' => '/home/myRemoteUser/'
    ]
```

#### Try 1

`SSH::into('S2')->run(['mkdir imAtestDirectory']);`

Each time I tried to use `SSH::into('S2')` I'm getting an `Unable to connect to remote server` RuntimeException.

I tried without any SSH key, with my private/public SSH key in the **keytext** field but I'm still getting the same error.

I tried to put the path to my keys in the **key** field, but it says the file `~/.ssh/mykey` doesn't exist.

Moving my keys to another place isn't working either, I'm getting the `Unable to connect to remote server` again.

#### Try 2

`SSH::into('S1')->run(['ssh -tt -p 2222 myRemoteUser@myRemoteIp', 'mkdir testDir'])`

I tried to reproduce exactly what I was doing in command line because I know that can work. I feel like I'm connecting to S2, when I'm looking at what the SSH command is returning I'm getting `[...] The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software [...]` which is the same message I'm getting when I'm doing the command in command line , but it's not creating the folder.

---

## Help me, please

I'm running out of ideas, I've been googling for hours but I can't find how to resolve my problem or any other way of doing what I want to do what I want.

If you need any more precision, feel free to ask.

---

## Edits

1. I've been trying few other syntax but without success. I'm still open to any suggestions, I'll try next what Dammeul said (check if port 2222 is open on both ends)

Comment: Is port 2222 open on both ends?

Comment: I can use `telnet myRemoteHost 2222` from S1.    
I can't use `telnet myHost 2222` from S2.

Comment: Sounds like the port is closed on S2 potentially. Worth checking if you can open it / see if it is open

Comment: Wouldn't be a problem as well for when I'm using `ssh -tt -p 2222 myRemoteUser@myRemoteIp` in command line as well then? (Because this is working perfectly ...)

Comment: You wouldn't use your public key for authentication.  What user is the web server running as?  Does it have access to your key?

Comment: That's what I thought but wasn't sure so I tried both. When I'm running `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` I can see that www-data is running the apache server (or root, maybe you have a better way to find it). I don't know if it has access to my key. But when I create a folder on S1 via Laravel (`SSH::into('S1')->run(['mkdir testFolder']);`), via `ls -Flash`I can see that the owner is myUsername, and myUsername should have the rights to access my key.

Comment: Why do you have to do this via SSH? Why not enable the scripts for public use and protect them with some authorization mechanism?

Comment: I don't specifically have to use SSH I guess. I choose to use it because I though it would be easy to do what i wanted to do.
Do you have any example of what you're talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your actually can log in via "Try 2" you should run the code differently. Append your command with your ssh command. What you are doing now is first running ssh (which probably hangs) and then running "mkdir" when ssh finishes. Instead:

```
SSH::into('S1')->run(['ssh -tt -p 2222 myRemoteUser@myRemoteIp "cd && mkdir testDir"'])
```

(I also added `cd` to make sure you are in your home directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Your solution works perfectly ! I feel dumb about not trying that kind of syntax though

Answer (score -4):

ssh may be used with following steps by using ip , port and ssh password.

1. open cmd prompt.
2. enter ssh root@191.123.2.3 -p 23202  (ip - 191.123.2.3, port - 23202).
3. if asking for authentication with yes/no, type yes and enter.
4. cd /var/www/html/

your ssh cmd promt will start.